# Use onclick or a class to target voting on a submission with an arrow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would it be better to use the method reddit uses when placing a vote by using `<a onclick="vote('4')">` or should I just add a class selector like `<a class='vote-up' id='4'>` or is the difference negligible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only use a class, you will still need to use JavaScript to attach an event handler to process the vote.

So you don't need to put the `onclick` into the markup, but you will need to assign the `click` property to everything with the class:

```
// Assuming you have your `vote()` function already
$("a.vote-up").click(function() {
  vote(this.id);
});
```

This can be done in `$(document).ready()`, or using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach to newly created elements as well.

Comment: Cool thanks. That's actually how I had it originally, but then I was looking @ reddit's and wondered if their method was better.

Answer (score 1):

It is really up to you to chose which is best, in either case, you still need to assign an "onclick" event which will do the ajax request(I assume).

I would use the first method because it is simpler, but I would use vote( this, '4' ) so that in the vote method you can get the attribute of the "sender" and even disable it like

```
function vote( sender, votecnt ) {
  // do the ajax request
  // ... more code ...
  // disable future vote for the already voted item
  $( sender ).unbind( "click" ); // <-- assuming that the onclick event was set using javascript and not the onclick attribute
};
```